# How to send prototype method as a callback in javascript?

Tags: javascript, callback, this, box2d

I have prototype method that is activated by a callback from the Box2D API I am using. The callback can get to the function, but it is not the correct instance of the function. What is the proper syntax to get the callback to call *this*.prototype class.

The call to the Box2D API:

```
Box2d.prototype.getBodyAtMouse = function() {
   this.mousePVec = new this.b2Vec2(this.mouseX/this.SCALE, this.mouseY/this.SCALE);
   var aabb = new this.b2AABB();
   aabb.lowerBound.Set(this.mouseX/this.SCALE - 0.001, this.mouseY/this.SCALE - 0.001);
   aabb.upperBound.Set(this.mouseX/this.SCALE + 0.001, this.mouseY/this.SCALE + 0.001);
   this.selectedBody = null;
   var _this = this; 
   this.world.QueryAABB(_this.getBodyCB, aabb);
   return this.selectedBody;
```

}

This is the box2D API Method that is called:

```
b2World.prototype.QueryAABB = function (callback, aabb) {
  var __this = this;
  var broadPhase = __this.m_contactManager.m_broadPhase;

  function WorldQueryWrapper(proxy) {
     return callback(broadPhase.GetUserData(proxy));
  };
  broadPhase.Query(WorldQueryWrapper, aabb);
```

}

And this is the callback that I want the API to have the proper reference to:

```
Box2d.prototype.getBodyCB = function(fixture) 
{
  if(fixture.GetBody().GetType() != this.b2Body.b2_staticBody) {
   if(fixture.GetShape().TestPoint(fixture.GetBody().GetTransform(), this.mousePVec)) {
      selectedBody = fixture.GetBody();
      return false;
   }
}
return true;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Either use

```
var _this = this; 
this.world.QueryAABB(function(fix){
   _this.getBodyCB(fix);
}, aabb);
```

or

```
this.world.QueryAABB(this.getBodyCB.bind(this), aabb);
```

([which](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) is not supported by older browsers, but can easily be shimmed)